# How to handle caching and data-store sync in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a small appengine application and I want to start using Datastore.
My app has some users and each user is a complicated JAVA class.
Users might swap some "point" objects between them, so I need the data to be available and fast.

My question is quite generic:
How should I handle the data caching?
Storing the data entirely in the Datastore and fetching it in every call sounds slow in runtime.
On the other hand, holding the data in a static JAVA class sounds tricky, because every now and then the server resets and data is erased.
If I had a main loop, like in a regular console application I would've probably saved the data twice-three times a day on predefined hours of the day.
How should I manage my code in such a way that it would save the status in the datastore every now and then and this way will not loose any data.

Answer (score 0):

if the number of write operations are less than read operations,
it is good to try "Write-through caching" with memcache module.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/

basically the write-through caching works like this:

- for every write operations, program update the datastore, then backup the data to memcache
- for every read operations, program will try to read from memcache. if it can found required data, then it returns, otherwise it will fetch the data from datastore and backup the results to memcache.

Answer (score 0):

As @lucemia noted, you should use memcache.

If you use objectify, you can [set-up caching declaratively](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Caching), without writing and cache handling code.